# Is it possible to install ios 13 beta into ios Simulator?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I'm trying to debug a nativescript issue on ios 13 and can't figure out how to get the beta installed onto the simulator. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

**No it is not possible** to have **simulator with ios 13 installed**.The only way is to **update your xcode from app store to (11.0)**. Then there will be iphone 11 as a simulator in your simulators list with ios version 13.

Else you can connect your real device with xcode having ios 13 installed.But it will definitely required a higher/updated version of xcode.

Answer (score -3):

Xcode 11 beta has iOS 13 beta for simulator. 
Simulator beta is install also when install Xcode 11 beta. 
You can find iOS 13 on simulator beta.

Comment: My xcode beta 11 does not have any ios 13 simulators present - and no way that I can tell to add them.